# Angular 2 CLI - 3rd party JS plugins lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, lazy-loading, angular-cli

https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

I have used this for Angular 1, is there any alternative plugins like this to work for Angular 2? I want to include the 3rd party **Javascript** plugins on demand (lazy-load), into my Angular 2 project. So far no success.

I'm currently working on [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/). I have tried to include in `angular-cli.json` file, including jquery seems work. But I think this is for global load.

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
  ],
```

Let's say I want a page with `WOW.js` plugin in that page. I should call a component with WOW.js initiated inside it, then the `WOW.js` file will be included dynamically. How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add into your assets the WOW.js file in your angular-cli.json configuration file.

```
"assets": [
    "pathToYourPlugin/WOW.js"
  ],
```

Then into your component add a script tag to import your library.

```
<script src="/WOW.js"></script>
```

Comment: my component html template is just a partial for entire page. is it ok if i put this `<script src="/WOW.js"></script>` between <body> and not in <head>?

Comment: Yes of course. The recommended way is at the end of the body. This answer is not really beaytiful but it solves your requirement.

Comment: `<script src="assets/wow.js"></script>` didn't import. I confirmed can see scripts here `http://localhost:4200/assets/wow.js`.
when I do inspect the elements using dev tool, `<script src="assets/wow.js"></script>` tag is gone from html. please help. thanks

Comment: You should not add it through angular but through template or inner html.

Comment: Yes, I put it inside template `dashboard.component.html` file.

`@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'
})`

Comment: It seems it is sanitized. Can you it using innerHtml (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding)